# Grant access to only one bucket in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policies

I´m trying to write a policy to grant a specific user access to only one bucket

this is what I have so far:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I don´t want this user to list all other buckets
so I changed 
**"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"** to **"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET"**
but it didn´t work. I don´t need this user to access the console just programmatically is fine. thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to limit the results of the `ListAllMyBuckets` command. Either they see the list of **all the buckets**, or they see none at all.

If they know which bucket they wish to use, then you could simply **remove permission to list buckets**. They will still be able to list the *contents* of `MYBUCKET` and upload/download objects. They just won't be able to request a list of buckets. (And the S3 Management Console won't function because it expects to be able to list all buckets in the account)